# SonarQube 6.7.1- Project Search Issue, cannot find in UI

Tags: sonarqube

When we try to search for a specific project in SonarQube 6.7.1 version, say `Dev_Automation_Test_XML`

Few other projects also get listed and not filtered out.

Other projects names are:

- `Dev_Automation_Test_COBOL`
- `Dev_Automation_Test_C`

Is there any fix for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which string are you trying to search, but I tried it in Sonar 5.6.6 (older than yours) and it works like expected from my point of view.

Only idea which I got, if the newer versions are not possible to search also by project key (my version not), then it can be caused by same part in the project key, which are you maybe trying to search.

*suffix "Test"*
[image]

*suffix "Test_x"- only 1 project*
[image]

*suffix "Test_c" - two projects*
[image]

Comment: It aint working the same as 5.6.6 or 5.6.3 in the new 6.7.1 version